# Solr Exception: Unknown fieldType 'double' specified on field

Tags: solr, solr-schema

My solr schema.xml is defined as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="public" version="1.5">
  <fields>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="ranking" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <!—other fields —>
  </fields>

<uniqueKey>doc_id</uniqueKey>

 <types>
   <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
   <filedType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
   <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
 </types>

</schema>
```

The original schema didn't have the field type double and field ranking and everything works fine, but after I added them it kept throwing

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldType 'double' specified on field kb_ranking
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.loadFields(IndexSchema.java:648)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:471)
```

The two lines I added is defined in the same way as other fields, but why mine caused the issue?

After I changed the two lines of ranking and double to only one line as following:

```
<filedType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
```

It still throws: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldType 'solr.TrieDoubleField' specified on field ranking. But TrieDoulbeField is in the same package as TrieLongField.

I've been searched for solutions online for a day, but didn't find any solution that can fix my issue. I am new to solr. Could someone give me my suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be caused by a typo. I typed filedType instead of fieldType. But solr didn't complain about the syntax error.